# Zoom em gráfico C#

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, graphics

Tenho um gráfico de linha com valores de 0 a 5 para Y em minha aplicação *C#*. Como na maioria das vezes os valores que chegam para ser desenhados são de 2 a 3 gostaria de aplicar zoom verticalmente.

```
float atualdata_1, calibracao = 1;

private void timerPLAY_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    graphControl1.AddValue(atualdata_1 * calibracao_canal_1);
    //COMANDO QUE CHAMA O DESENHADOR
    //atualdata_1 tem valores de 0 a 5
    //calibracao_canal_1 seria o zoom aplicado
}
```

Estou tentando aplicar zoom multiplicando o valor atual de `atualdata_1` que é o valor a ser desenhado pelo fator de calibração `calibracao` antes de desenhar. Fiz uma comboBox para ficar alterando o valor de `calibracao` para `1,5; 2; 2,5;` etc. Porém, desta maneira eu acabo multiplicando todo o sinal, o que faz ele deslocar para cima, e o que eu quero é apenas expandi-lo para cima e para baixo. Segue controle em que desenho o gráfico:

```
 public class GraphControl : Control
    {
        public void AddValue(float value1)
        {
            _values1.Add(value1);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(95, 95, 95), 1.5f)) 
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            var wid = (float)Width / (float)_dataCount;
            var total = 5;

            //-------------------1-------------------------------

            var lastPoint1 = new PointF(0F, (float)(Height * 0.5F);
            PointF newPoint1 = new PointF();

            var idInit = _values1.Count - _dataCount;

            if (idInit < 0)
                idInit = 0;

            for (int i = idInit, a = 0; i < _values1.Count; i++, a++)
            {
                var value = (float)(_values1[i]);
                var porcent = value / total;

                if (porcent > 1) porcent = 1;
                var hg = porcent * Height;

                newPoint1.X = (a + 1) * wid;

                if (porcent >= 1) newPoint1.Y = Height - hg;
                else newPoint1.Y = Height - hg - 1;

                using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) 
                     e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint1, newPoint1);

                lastPoint1 = newPoint1;

                if(_values1.Count > 4000)
                {
                    _values1 = _values1.Skip(_values1.Count - 2000).ToList();
                    idInit = 0;
                    Invalidate();
                }
            }

            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
```

Para facilitar o entendimento segue imagem com explicação do efeito pretendido. Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema? Muito obrigado pela atenção[image: ![Efeito Pretendido]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma ideia seria retirar metade da `var total = 5` aos valores, ou seja `2.5`, que faria com que o grafico "descesse":

```
 float value = _values1[i] - total / 2 ;
```

Na porcentagem você calcularia o zoom, sendo `1.5f 66%`, `2f 100%` (dobro), etc..

```
float porcent = value / (total / _zoom);
```

E por fim fazer o grafico "subir":

```
PointF newPoint1 = new PointF
{
    X = (a + 1) * wid,
    Y = Height - (porcent * Height) - Height / 2
};
```

Comment: Não tinha pensado nesse conceito de descer o sinal e depois subir novamente. Fiz umas modificações e ficou show. Muito obrigado!!